# Удаляется DLL из SysWOW64 после перезагрузки

Tags: c++, windows-8, inno-setup, uac

Пишу инсталятор на InnoSetup для своей программы.

Программа регистрирует в системе две библиотеки и кладет их в system32 и syswow64, x64 и x86 соответственно. Но с включенным UAC по дефолту, после перезагрузки x86 DLL удаляется. Инсталятор выполняется с правами администратора, никаких ошибок.

Посоветуйте, как поступить? Пока только просматривается выход, просить во время установки пользователя отключать UAC на время установки?

ОС - Windows8, но и на 10ке такая же проблема. 
Проблемы начались, когда Microsoft выпустили какие то обновления системы безопасности.

Comment: Чьи это DLL? Ваши личные или от другой программы?

Comment: Dll и инсталлятор подписаны?

Comment: А зачем вы их в System кладете, они ж не системные. Положите рядом с программой.

Comment: Да, дллки собственные.. Это LSP драйвер, потому ложу в систем все, чтоб зарегестрировать... Ничего не подписано, проблему решил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решил, банально просто, указал атрибут system в инсталяторе для DLL, после перезагрузки система их теперь не трогает. Всем спасибо.